# How to enable video and picture using cordova-plugin-camera (ALLMEDIA)

Tags: cordova, ionic2, camera, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I would like to know how to invoke camera as well as video mode in ionic3 camera plugin.

I found that we have `mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA` will enable user for taking both video and picture.

After installing the camera plugin according to this [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```

**MYCODE**

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

constructor(private camera: Camera) { }

const options: CameraOptions = {
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((data) => {
console.log(data);
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
console.log(err);
});
```

> I am not able to enable both video and picture after invoking camera plugin
>
> the above code is only enabling to take only picture(I'm not able to switch to video mode)

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem.

According to the plugin's documentation, video is not supported for camera mode, only for photo library and saved photo album mode:

```
Name: mediaType
Type: MediaType
Default: PICTURE    
Description: Set the type of media to select from. Only works when PictureSourceType is PHOTOLIBRARY or SAVEDPHOTOALBUM.
```

Source: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameracameraoptions--object